# 2001 Tacoma - Consistent belt chrip/squeak noise

Tags: toyota, noise, belt, tacoma

2001 Toyota Tacoma 2WD 2.4L 4cyl

92k Miles

I have a chirp/squeak coming from the area near my power steering belt.

When I spray it with water the noise goes away, but quickly comes back.

[**Here's a video of the noise and water test**](https://youtu.be/ckFZrEBgRyA)

Happens consistently - both from a cold start and when warmed up.

All 3 accessory belts (power steering, AC, alternator) are less than a year old; replaced about 1k miles ago. Continental belts.

It's just recently started (i.e. it didn't start after putting on the new belts)

Don't have a calibrator for the tension, but it doesn't feel loose.

[Here's a video of the noise and water test...](
https://youtu.be/ckFZrEBgRyA)

My next test will be to remove the belt and try spinning the power steering pulley manually, checking for play/noises, but was curious to hear what others think/where they would start.

Comment: What quality of belt did you buy when you replaced them? Its definitely belt noise, worn out pulley belt grooves can cause this also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensioner for the power steering was loose and wobbly. Tightened it up and the noise went away.